# Is there any way to test file upload in Rspec using a public URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I am a newbie to Spec and I was wondering if it is possible to test file uploads without actually having the file in our public folder. After upload I save the file to S3. At present I have this code.

```
file = ActionController::TestUploadedFile.new('./spec/fixtures/files/IMG_8880.jpg')
attach["attachment#{i+1}"] = file
attachment_in["attachment#{i+1}"] = {:filename => "IMG_8880.jpg", 
                                     :name => "IMG_8880.jpg", 
                                     :type => 'image/jpeg'}
```

I am using rails 2.3.8 and hence fixture_file_upload is not available. I hope there is a way wherein I can avoid having the image file in my fixtures folder and fetch it from some URL.

Comment: What gem do you use for uploading? `carrierwave` or `paperclip`?

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling your going to need to use Mocking and Stubbing in this case.

You want to test that;

```
ActionController::TestUploadedFile.should_recieve(:new).with('SOME_MOCK_OBJECT')
```

You can setup the 
`SOME_MOCK_OBEJCT`by

```
SOME_MOCK_OBJECT = double 'SOME_MOCK_OBJECT'
```

You'll need to look into Stubbing and Mocking, here's a good [video](http://blog.codeship.io/2013/06/11/testing-tuesday-9-stubbing-and-mocking-with-rspec.html) or you can try out Code Schools Rspec.